# Inheriting different concrete realisations of an abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

There is a basic abstract class `Subj`:

```
public abstract class Subj
{
    public IName name;
    public string ID { get; set; }
    //other members of the class
}
```

It has 2 derived classes: `Company` and `Person`:

```
public class Company : Subj
{
    //realise interface IName
    public new  IName name = new NameCompany();
}

public class Person : Subj
{
    //realise interface IName
    public new IName name = new NamePerson();
}
```

There is also `Client` class that expand functionality of `Subj`

```
public class Client : Subj
{
    //Client functionality
    //Gets folder name for a client
    public string foldername()
    {
    }
    //The list of Legal cases
    private List<LCase> _cases = new List<LCase> { };
}
```

The problem is, `Subj` must be realised as either `Company` or `Person` and then it may or may not be "expanded" into `Client`, which brings me to inheriting `Client` from `Company` and `Person`, but multiple inheritance is prohibited, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: " how do I solve this problem?" - by using a language that support algebraic type systems. Otherwise, welcome to OOP design **hell**. Data-modelling using classes is difficult.

Comment: Don't use inheritance

Comment: @Fabio "Composition over inheritance" is a guideline, not a rule - and it's often unhelpful because composition cannot be used to represent "is" relationships, only "has" relationships.

Comment: I think `Company` and `Person` should **not** inherit from `Subj`, instead they should "own" their own `Subj` instances (I assume `Subj` is an abbreviation for "Subject" - please use understandable terms when sharing your program code). Other than that, I like @OlivierRogier's updated answer (though I'd change the constraint from `where T : Subj, new()` to `where T : IHasSubject` instead).

Comment: @Dai, `Company` and `Person` are different objects with different behaviour, the fact that both have properties with same names doesn't make them similar from business logic point of view. "Don't use inheritance" means that those objects shouldn't share logic only because it looks similar. Start building data models without separately and only after few months of working software when you actually see that both Company and Person changes for same reasons - consider to put this behaviour into one place.

Comment: @Fabio That's my point, they **are** different entities, that's why I said they *should not* both inherit from `Subj`. However your remark that "Start building data models without separately and only after few months..." sounds grossly out-of-touch with actual LoB software development: we don't have "months" to determine if a design is good or not - teams have to iterate in days, not months (if not hours).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to multiple inheritence that mix ancestors.

Using composition and generic might solve the problem, but because generic parameter constraint does not allow the OR operator yet, you can check the type in the constructor to throw a design exception at runtime.

Here is a hack:

```
public class Client<T> where T : Subj, new()
{
  readonly T Item = new T();
  public Client()
  {
    var type = typeof(T);
    if ( type != typeof(Person) && type != typeof(Company) )
    {
      string msg = "Generic type parameter for Client must be Person or Company."
                 + Environment.NewLine
                 + type.Name + " provided.";
      throw new TypeAccessException(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

You can refactor that to use a list of allowed types.

You should be able to use an interface design, but that will complicate things and reduce the typing you want if I understood the question correctly.

If all Subj childs are allowed, no need to check the type.

Usage:

```
public class OtherSubj : Subj
{
}

var clientPerson = new Client<Person>();    // ok
var clientCompany = new Client<Company>();  // ok
var clientOther = new Client<OtherSubj>();  // exception
```

You can also create classes:

```
public class ClientPerson : Client<Person>
{
}

public class ClientCompany : Client<Company>
{
}
```

You can either publish the compound instance and name it what you want:

```
public readonly T Item = new T();
```

Or offer properties and methods wrappers:

```
private readonly T Item = new T();

public IName name 
{ 
  get => Item.name;
  set => Item.name = value;
}
```

Comment: Subclassing is static, not dynamic - `Person` **and** `Company` cannot both subclass `Client` - and the OP said that `Person` and `Company` are **not** `Client` instances by default - so I'm not sure what your answer is trying to say. Additionally your answer says to use generic types, but your answer doesn't contain any generic code.

Comment: @Dai I don't see anything static. But for the other thing you wrote, are you sure? I understood that the PO need Client be a Person or a Company...

Comment: Could you please add code on how to correctly make an instance of `Client` in your solution? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier By "static" I'm referring to the _static type system_ of the program, not the `static` keyword. (Whereas if you compare C#/.NET to JavaScript, in JavaScript "subclassing" is dynamic, not static, because subtypes can be defined and implemented at runtime, e.g. by messing with `TypeName.prototype` and so on).

Comment: @IgorCheglakov I wrote answer too quickly but I've updated it and now it is usable.

Comment: @Dai I understand, thank you. Indeed. So the suggested hack using generic and composition, ideally with a wrapping design to be clean and robust.

Comment: @Olivier i'm sorry, but I don't get something: In your resonse you have made a constructor for `Client` which validates it's generic type parameter. But where is the code which uses said generic type in the construction of the `client` or am I missing something?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov In example usage paragraph: `var clientPerson = new Client<Person>();` or later where I define classes for convenience. So the Person instance is embbedded in the class by [composition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/). So the need to offer a public access to this `Item`, or better, to create a wrapping design to offer a real business entity. The wrapper design requires to write some off-putting code but doing that you don't need to repeat business logic factored in Subj and avoid accessing Item from exterior.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov So putting `Item` (Person or Company) public or creating a wrapper depends on how clean and scrupulous you want to be, if you have the time. Either way, you keep the hierarchical structure you design but not direct polymorphism.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, so, the `Person / Company` is just stored as a member of `Client` class instead of lending it's members directly to `Client`? I.e. to access `.name` property I have to use `myclient.Item.name` instead of `myclient.name`? It's how I made it to begin with long ago, except for the type cheching.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov That's it. Using Item directly or a wrapping design. It is called [composition over inheritence](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/inheritance-vs-composition/) if you want to search and [learn more](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm) using books and the web. Here you can use this [principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) with generics and the type cheking hack to solve your problem because you can't define a class that inherits one OR another, and generic type parameter constraint doesn't support OR yet.